# Microsoft windows server 2016 crashes while executing Photoshop as a remote app

Tags: windows-server-2016, remoteapp

In an institute I have installed windows server 2016 and published adobe photoshop as a remote application. Any Time, about 12 users connect to the server and using it simultaneously. At this time server crashes multiple times and the blue page is shown with stop code: "RDR File System".

The Server is a virtual machine on the vmware ESXi hypervisor with 32GB of memory, 16 vCPUs and about 300GB hard disk. I guess that the resources are not sufficient for this number of users, but I cannot estimate the amount of required resources.

Is my guess correct? Would you please help me to make a decision on the amount of required resources?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you opened the event viewer and looked at the error messages that are displayed?  It is not likely your server is being pushed to it's limits.  check this article:

http://www.solvusoft.com/en/errors/blue-screen-errors/microsoft-corporation/windows-operating-system/bug-check-0x27-rdr-file-system/

Also you can open the task manager on an administrator account, and click on users while you have about 10 or 11 users logged in and get an idea of what the overall usage is.  If you're maxing out your server then make a judgement from there on what to increase your specs to.